# Load images into a Bootstrap carousel from Database MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I have a working Bootstrap carousel with images source insert into HTML code. I need to load images (and some others data like title and description) from Mysql database using PHP code. I tried PHP code alone and it works, but when I tried to implement it into original HTML code, it not works.

This is Carousel HTML code:

```
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">


    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="" contenteditable="false"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active" contenteditable="false"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="" contenteditable="false"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3" class="" contenteditable="false"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4" class="" contenteditable="false"></li>

    </ol>



    <div class="carousel-inner">


        <div class="item" style="">
            <img src="images/slide/slide-1.jpg" alt="" class="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4 class="">First Slide Title</h4>
                <p class="">
                   Description for First Slide, this First Slide.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="item active">
            <img src="images/slide/slide-2.jpg" alt="" class="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4 class="">Second Slide Title</h4>

                <p class="">
                   Description for Second Slide, this is Second Slide.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="item" style="">
            <img src="images/slide/slide-3.jpg" alt="" class="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4 class="">Third Slide Title</h4>

                            <p class="">
                   Description for Third Slide, this is Third Slide.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>


         <div class="item" style="">
            <img src="images/slide/slide-4.jpg" alt="" class="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4 class="">Third Slide Title</h4>

                            <p class="">
                   Description for Third Slide, this is Third Slide.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>


         <div class="item" style="">
            <img src="images/slide/slide-5.jpg" alt="" class="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h4 class="">Third Slide Title</h4>

                            <p class="">
                   Description for Third Slide, this is Third Slide.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>


    </div> 


    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>


</div>
```

This is my PHP code (alone):

```
    <?php


$servername = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
$username = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT id AS id, title AS title, imagename AS imagename, description AS description, status AS status FROM uploadslide ORDER BY id";

 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){



?>

        <div class="item" style="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            <?php echo '<img src="uploads/slide/' .$row['imagename']. '" alt="" class="" /> '?>
                <h4 class=""><?php echo $row['title'] ?></h4>
                <p class="">
                   <?php echo $row['description'] ?>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php 

}
    mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

And this is my HTML + PHP code (Together):

```
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade">


    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="" contenteditable="false"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="active" contenteditable="false"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="" contenteditable="false"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3" class="" contenteditable="false"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4" class="" contenteditable="false"></li>

    </ol>



    <div class="carousel-inner">


       <?php


$servername = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
$username = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
$password = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
$dbname = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT id AS id, title AS title, imagename AS imagename, description AS description, status AS status FROM uploadslide ORDER BY id";

 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){



?>

        <div class="item" style="">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
            <?php echo '<img src="uploads/slide/' .$row['imagename']. '" alt="" class="" /> '?>
                <h4 class=""><?php echo $row['title'] ?></h4>
                <p class="">
                   <?php echo $row['description'] ?>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php 

}
    mysqli_close($conn);

?>


    </div> 

    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
    </a>

    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </a>


</div>
```

I get my page without carousel. I am getting crazy about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first add a field in your database table for called item.
Now for the particular image you want to show first in that field set it active then set your carousel like

```
 <div class="item" <?php echo $row['item']; ?>>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
```

this should make it show

Comment: I added item field in my table, I added that code you wrote in my code, but I don't understand what I have to do more. I have to add a value in item field? thanks

Comment: what you should put in that field is active. Then in your code use this      <div class="item" <?php echo $row['item']; ?>>
        <div class="carousel-caption">     instead of       <div class="item" style="">
        <div class="carousel-caption">

Comment: ok, I did it but it's not working... I don't know if I did right your suggest: I added item and insert value into it and I wrote that code you said...nothing :( any other suggest?